# Load changes made in another DbContext

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-5

I have a WPF app that has a grid with a list of data that I loaded with EF. Some other window can make changes to the same data loaded on the grid but using a different dbcontext instance. How can I see the changed data on the grid? I know I can refresh a single entity with `ctx.Entry<MyEntity>(instance).Reload();` - but I want to see all the changes and no matter what I do, I only see the old values. I can't use `AsNoTracking` neither create a new `DbContext` instance in this case.

Comment: Why you cannot use `AsNoTracking`?

Comment: Because the user can make changes directly to the grid and save it.

Comment: But in such case you can have edited not saved data and the reload can cause these data to be different? How do you want to resolve such issue?

Comment: I did not think about this yet but I think it is reasonable to imagine that after the reload I would lose all my pending changes on those reloaded entities. But most of the time, the data will not be edited on the grid so this should not be a big problem. To me looks like a very simple case and I cannot see why EF don't just update the values of the entities. I get that is an entirely different concept but I like the simplicity of RIA Services on which to avoid this problem I can just call `Load` (on the client) passing a `LoadBehavior.RefreshCurrent` or even `LoadBehavior.MergeIntoCurrent`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> To me looks like a very simple case and I cannot see why EF don't just
>   update the values of the entities.

EF has this mechanism as well but it is not exposed on DbContext API. You need to get back to ObjectContext. If you just want to reload set of entities you will call:

```
var objectContext = ((IObjectContextAdapter)dbContext).ObjectContext;
objectContext.Refresh(RefreshMode.StoreWins, listOfEntitiesToReload);
```

`RefreshMode.StoreWins` causes all pending changes to be overwritten by reloaded values. You can also use `RefreshMode.ClientWins` which will keep your changes and merge them with reloaded data. The problem with this approach is that it only reloads entities you already have. You will not get new entities.

If you want to get new entities as well you must execute a query and you must tell EF that you want to reload values:

```
var objectContext = ((IObjectContextAdapter)dbContext).ObjectContext;
var objectSet = objectContext.CreateObjectSet<MyEntity>();
objectSet.MergeOption = MergeOption.OverwriteChanges;
var result = objectSet.Where(...).ToList();
```

Again `MergeOption.OverwriteChanges` overwrites all pending changes but you can use `MergeOption.PreserveChanges` to merge reloaded values to your edited values.

I think there can be still some issues with refreshing values with some relations and maybe also entities which were deleted in the database.

Comment: This is exactly what I need, thank you, my faith on EF is restored :)

Comment: @ladislav-mrnka One question, is that last step really necessary? If I understood you correctly, EF will only recognize changes to records that italready has loaded and merge them the first way. So If you were to add a new row to a table manually it would not get updated into the dbcontext using the first way? I just tried this and I saw no need for the second way. Maybe the behavior got changed or I completely misunderstood you? :)