# How to load database changes?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, .net-4.0, entity-framework-5

- I am using Entity Framework 5 along with SQL Server 2008 R2.
- I also implemented the repository pattern.
- It's a desktop application

My system is working nicely, besides one "little" detail.
When two or more users are using the app and one changes the data the other doesn't see it if he doesn't leave and re-enter the app.
I got Ladislav's answer here: [Load changes made in another DbContext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12246462/load-changes-made-in-another-dbcontext)

And it worked. The only problem is that for each collection I want to make sure it's updated I have to hard code it.

Even though it works, I can't help to think that there must be a better way to this.
I don't think that Entity Framework doesn't know when the database was changed and need to re-retrieve the data.

So, what am I doing wrong?

This is what I'm doing so far:

```
public class MyAppContext : DbContext 
{
    //DbSet<T> declarations
}

public class Context : IDisposable
{
    private readonly MyAppContext ctx;
    private Dictionary<Type, IRepository> repositories;

    private static Context instance;

    public static Context Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (instance == null)
                instance = new Context();

            return instance;
        }
    }
    ...
}

// and then each repository have access to the context
public abstract class Repository<T> : IRepository
    where T : class
{
    protected readonly MyAppContext ctx;
    ...
}
```

As you can see I use the "singleton" pattern to access the context and avoid dual context exceptions.

Any ideas?

Comment: You can use this to get notification http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms130764.aspx

Comment: @Blam Is this the only way? Can't this be done via EntityFramework? Thanks.